# Описание namespace в заголовочном файле

Tags: c++, namespace

Возник вопрос по поводу описания `namespace`ов. Не пойму как они должны быть описаны в заголовочном файле, чтобы при подключении этого заголовочного файла можно было напрямую обращаться к идентификатору `namespace`а.

Например:

```
namespace whizbangStartData
{
  float     wSD_speed = static_cast<float>(0.2);
  const int wSD_UpX = 966, wSD_UpY = 303;
  const int wSD_RightX = 1035, wSD_RightY = 303;
  const int wSD_DownX = 1014, wSD_DownY = 303;
  const int wSD_LeftX = 987, wSD_LeftY = 303;
  const int wSD_Width = 20, wSD_Height = 20;
}
namespace wsd = whizbangStartData;
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> error LNK2005: "float whizbangStartData::wSD_speed" 
> (?wSD_speed@whizbangStartData@@3MA) already defined in BattleCity.obj
> ```

Comment: приведи пример кода чтобы было понятнее

Comment: @ampawd
    SomeClass.h
    #include "OtherClass.h"

    someNamespace::someData

Как в файле OtherClass.h или, может быть, cpp, должно быть описано ПИ someNamespace?

Comment: о господи вставьте этот код в вопрос а не в коментарий чтобы можно было почеловечески прочитать

Comment: да тут есть 4 слова, что не понятного?

Comment: а в чём тут проблема ?? в заголовочном файле пишите `namespace someNamespace { int someData = 123; }` например

Comment: И выдаёт ошибки, мол эти данные уже объявлены в проекте, и указывает просто файл с main. А там ничего этого нет, да и вообще эти данные имеют уникальные имена.

Comment: приведите полный код и скопируйте ошибку, не черта не разберёшь откуда ошибка

Comment: а Вы используете файл с этим классом в нескольких файлах?

Comment: Да использую, этот файл подключается к базовому классу и получается, что и в наследниках он есть.

Comment: Ваша проблема - в том, что `wSD_speed` у вас почему-то не является константой. Если это "так и должно быть" - то вам надо вынести объявление этой переменной в один из модулей компиляции, а в заголовочном файле подключать ее как extern.

Comment: Скорее всего в OtherClass.h вам нужно использовать `#pragma once` в самом начале файле, попробуйте

Comment: Это всё есть, но попробую сделать константой, ведь действительно ошибка только с этим полем.

Comment: Так и есть, получается можно использовать только константы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как должно быть известно, строка вида `#include <filename>` приводит к вставке содержимого файла `filename` вместо этой строки. Т.е., подключая файл в какой-либо модуль `X` получим:

```
namespace whizbangStartData
{
  float     wSD_speed = static_cast<float>(0.2);
  const int wSD_UpX = 966, wSD_UpY = 303;
  ...
}

// содержимое модуля X
```

Отдельные модули (единицы трансляции) компилируются независимо друг от друга. И когда модулей, включающих упомянутый файл больше одного, получим, что имена `wSD_speed`, `wSD_UpX` и т.д. присутствуют в каждом модуле. При этом, для констант неявно используется внутренняя линковка (т.е. они не видны из другого модуля, если явно не помечены как `extern`) и поэтому компоновщик не видит с ними проблем при объединении нескольких модулей. Другое дело - переменная. `wSD_speed` не является константой и наличие её в пространстве имен делает её видимой другим модулям (т.е. для таких переменных предполагается неявный `extern`). Получается, что в процессе компоновки при использовании `whizbangStartData::wSD_speed` в коде, становится неясно какую же область памяти реально использовать и компоновщик выводит соответствующее сообщение.

Исключить ошибку компоновки можно несколькими способами:

- Объявить переменную в хедере как `extern float wSD_speed;`, а определить только в одном из модулей.
- Добавить `static` перед `float`. Это сделает переменную невидимой извне модуля, т.е. в каждом модуле будет свой экземпляр `wSD_speed`.

Сомнительно, что подходящим будет именно второй вариант, но тем не менее, проблему компоновки он решает.

Answer (score 1):

Главная проблема в том, что вы **определяете переменную**, а не константу, в заголовочном файле. Результат - у вас нарушается правило одного определения: в каждом из объектных файлов имеется по одинаковому имени, и линковщик просто сходит с ума, не понимая, что вы от него хотите.